# How to refresh webview every 5 seconds

Tags: iphone

How can I refresh or reload webview every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NSTimer` to call the method every 5 seconds and use `-reload` method of `UIWebview`

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(updateWeb) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)updateWeb
{
    [webView reload];
}
```

Comment: gr8. Happy coding. Accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: where do I place this snippet?

Answer (score 3):

```
you need to use `NSTimer`,
```

Check the below code as reference.

```
- (void) startTimer {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(showElapsedTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

`showElapsedTime` will be called after delay, you provide.

```
 -(void) showElapsedTime: (NSTimer *) timer {

  //Reload your webview here 
   [myWebView reload];
   //you also need to invalidate your NSTimer for some condition 
   if(SomeCondition)
      [timer invalidate]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I think you could also have the webview reload itself via javascript with the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method. Something like this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"setTimeout('location.reload(true);',5000);"];
```

Not useful in all situations, but maybe in some.